# Derby I can connect to an only table created first named FRIEND, all other are not found

Tags: glassfish-3, derby

I created my project in Eclipse, connected to DerbyDB SAMPLE, schema `APP`, created table

```
FRIEND (column NAME varchar primary key, column AGE int).
```

Then I connected to this database in Glassfish with EJB3.0 and printed all the table's info.

Then I created almost the same table

`FRIENDA (column NAME varchar primary key, column AGE int)` 
in DB SAMPLE, schema APP.

And Glassfish didn't see it or any other tables in SAMPLE,APP but the first one FRIEND.

If I write parameter `drop-and-create-table` any of the mentioned tables could be dropped or created, but I can't connect to them but the first created one (FRIEND).

`Persistence.xml` is similar.

Tell me, please, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your two different connections are using two different Derby databases. Since Derby makes it so easy to create a database, it's quite easy to get confused in this way.

Comment: Oh, I really don't know how EJB 3.0 @RequestScoped works. I have 1 persistence.xml for several entity-classes: Friend.class, Frienda.class, Userb.class and so on. So, the "persistence unit" and all the DBC-properties are identical. If your comment is the case, then it is better not to use such an assembly (@RequestScoped EJB 3.0, Derby, Eclipse and Glassfish). Thanks a lot!